# Profile Image ruining elements on entire page

Tags: html, css, django

I'm building a blog as my first project in web dev. I've encountered an issue where, when I add a profile image next to the user's name, chaos ensues.

Running this same code on here seems to show it working correctly, however it is not. Any ideas?

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

[How the formatting should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YifK.png)

[Chaos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A4I1.png)

```css
body {
  background: url('redpattern.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: auto;
/*  color: #333333;*/
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

#ruleslist {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#holly  {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 90%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #000000;
}

#sidebar  {
  color: #000000;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}


bg-steel {
  color: #b52525;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #208ee8;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 5500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #418ac9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}
  <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}"
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
  <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
  <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:" l, F d, Y @ P" }}</small>
  </div>
  <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
  <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
</article>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You should post only required code to show the problem because it's harder to check what is wrong if you have all this "mess". You should edit your question and remove everything that is not required here, example: `{% extends "blog/base.html" %}`.

Comment: Your image tag isn’t closed properly. Add /> after the src attribute

Comment: Sidenote - you don't need slash to close img tags. `<img src="" alt="">`.

Comment: I don't think this is related to django (unless your image is not getting displayed). This is related to css and html only. But still I would suggest you to do this: `<a href='url-where-wanna-redirect-to'><span >{{post.author.username}}</span> &nbsp; <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}"></a>`

Comment: @SidTheBeard oh my goodness. I can't believe it was something that simple. Thank you

Comment: @JakubMuda is right, the slash is not necessary. I’m used to React Development which requires the closing slash but for regular HTML either way is valid.

Comment: @JakubMuda My apologies, I was completely unsure where this problem was coming from and thought it could be some weird format thing with CSS. Will definitely do this in the future. Thank you so much for your help